# How to show that these two versions of the Segre map are equal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products

Let $V_1$, $V_2$ be vector spaces  of dimension n+1 and m+1 respectively and $\mathbb{P}(V_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(V_2)$ their projectivization.

Rigorously, the Segre map is the function

$\sigma_{n,m} : \mathbb{P}(V_1) \times \mathbb{P}(V_2)  \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}: ([x_0,...,x_n],[y_0,...,y_m]) \rightarrow [x_0y_0, x_0y_1,...,x_0y_m,x_1y_0,...,x_iy_j,...,x_ny_m]$.

But there exists another definition used in Quantum Physics viewed in the light of algebraic geometry, which is (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding)

$\sigma_{n,m} : \mathbb{P}(V_1) \times \mathbb{P}(V_2) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V_1 \otimes V_2) : ([v],[w]) \rightarrow [v \otimes w]$

where $\otimes$ refers to the tensor product of vector spaces.

I don't understand how to show that these two definitions are equivalent, if they are so.

Comment: $\otimes$ is used as the symbol for the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding, I think that $\otimes$ refers to the tensor product in this second definition of the Segre map. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what your definition of $\sigma_{n,m}$ in the second setting is? The first thing that shows up on the Wikipedia page is just the coordinate map you've written down.

Comment: This is the Segre map, which maps two [v] and [w] to [v $\otimes$ w], whose image is called the Segre variety. In the context of quantum mechanics, this latter is seen as the set of decomposable multilinear forms. I edited my post to make it clear, is it ok now ?

Comment: Did you try choosing a basis of $V_1$ and $V_2$ and decomposing $v\otimes w$ in the corresponding basis of $V_1\otimes V_2$?

Comment: Your first formula for $\sigma_{n,m}$ is a little awkward, because it actually depends on a choice of basis for $V_1$ and $V_2$, so it makes more sense to define it as a map $\mathbb{P}^{n}\times \mathbb{P}^{m}\to \mathbb{P}^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_0,\cdots,a_n$ are a basis for $V_1$ and $b_0,\cdots,b_m$ are a basis for $V_2$, then $a_i\otimes b_j$ are a basis for $V_1\otimes V_2$. In particular, if you have a pair of vectors $\sum_i x_ia_i$ and $\sum_j y_jb_j$ where the $x_i$ and $y_j$ are scalars, then you get a vector $\sum_{i,j} x_iy_j (a_i\otimes b_j)$. So the map in coordinates from sending $([v],[w])\to [v\otimes w]$ has as its coordinate representation exactly the description you've started with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that I understand better the link between these two definitions :)